# Section with only pictures in it not occupying any padding

Tags: html, css

I have a section with only pictures in it and the problem is that it is not occupying any padding at all, so that section after that actually covers the picture section fully. In order to fix it I have to add ridiculously high padding to pictures section (about 60rem) and I am pretty sure it is not the right way to do it. Can anyone please help me with this?

https://jsfiddle.net/3nyLrce8/6/

HTML:

```
    <ul class="meals-showcase__list">
      <li class="meals-showcase__item">
        <figure class="meals-showcase__figure">
          <img class="meals-showcase__figure__img" src="resources/img/1.jpg" alt="Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="meals-showcase__list">
      <li class="meals-showcase__item">
        <figure class="meals-showcase__figure">
          <img class="meals-showcase__figure__img" src="resources/img/2.jpg" alt="Simple Italian pizza with cherry tomatoes">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="meals-showcase__list">
      <li class="meals-showcase__item">
        <figure class="meals-showcase__figure">
          <img class="meals-showcase__figure__img" src="resources/img/3.jpg" alt="Chicken breast steak with vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="meals-showcase__list">
      <li class="meals-showcase__item">
        <figure class="meals-showcase__figure">
          <img class="meals-showcase__figure__img" src="resources/img/4.jpg" alt="Autumn pumpkin soup">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="meals-showcase">

    <ul class="meals-showcase__list">
      <li class="meals-showcase__item">
        <figure class="meals-showcase__figure">
          <img class="meals-showcase__figure__img" src="resources/img/5.jpg" alt="Paleo beef steak with vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="meals-showcase__list">
      <li class="meals-showcase__item">
        <figure class="meals-showcase__figure">
          <img class="meals-showcase__figure__img" src="resources/img/6.jpg" alt="Healthy baguette with egg and vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="meals-showcase__list">
      <li class="meals-showcase__item">
        <figure class="meals-showcase__figure">
          <img class="meals-showcase__figure__img" src="resources/img/7.jpg" alt="Burger with cheddar and bacon">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="meals-showcase__list">
      <li class="meals-showcase__item">
        <figure class="meals-showcase__figure">
          <img class="meals-showcase__figure__img" src="resources/img/8.jpg" alt="Granola with cherries and strawberries">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.meals-showcase {

  &__list {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &__item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
  }

  &__figure {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;

    &__img {
      opacity: .7;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      transform: scale(1.15);
      transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s;

      &:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.04);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: edit your question and post the code you have tried

Comment: please add a jsfiddle or sth. equal

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3nyLrce8/1/

Comment: @KristjanRanna Please edit your answer to include that link.

Comment: I replaced images with random image. Even when you inspect section-meals with developer tools then you can clearly see that it is not occupying any padding.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code here; can you please update the Sass you are using to the compiled CSS? Unless your question is specifically with how to do something in Sass...

Comment: Tyler, CSS version here: https://jsfiddle.net/3nyLrce8/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using floats, you'll need to `clear` after the divs that are set to float. Set this on your parent div:

```
.meals-showcase__list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table;
  clear: both; }
```

Also, you don't need to use `<ul>` for each image. The parent should be `<ul>` with `<li>` children.I've updated the JSFiddle. There's a new `<section>` below the images.

https://jsfiddle.net/3nyLrce8/37/